# Unable to use $xml->ROW with value extracted from $_GET variable

Tags: php, url, get

I need to extruct the last letter after `'?p='` in a **URL** with `GET`?

> Example: http://www.example.com/test.php?p=1

How can I get only those numbers `1`

I think this is the right methode to get my URL and put it in a variable:

```
$numbers = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

If so, how can I get only those numbers in order to put them in a variable?

It seems like an obvious questions but the $_GET["p"] doesn't work??

Here is the code.

```
if(isset($_GET["p"]))
{
    //var_dump($_GET["p"]); // This var_dump displays the correct number 1 which is correct but when I put it in a variable and use that variable I get an error that says "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\Store_Locator\test2.php on line 21". 

 $myVariable = $_GET["p"]; // When I write $myVariable = 1; it works!

        echo '<p><strong>ID:</strong> '.$xml->ROW[$myVariable]->FIELD1.'</p>'; // This is line 21
}
```

By the way, I am trying to display data from an XML file.

Best Regards,

Comment: `$_GET['p']` it's that simple

Comment: Isn't it too obvious? Should have used Google instead of going through the trouble of creating a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myVariable = $_GET["p"];
```

This is the GET method, try to dig deeper into the questions you're asking, a google search might come in handy

**EDIT:**

The problem here isn't as described, I will update your question, but your solution is to cast the value you're getting to int. For some reason it's not auto-casting as usual.

on line 18, after getting your variable, do the following:

```
$i = $_GET["p"]; 
$i = (int)$i;
```

It will work then. Cheers!

Comment: I asked this question because when I use $myVariable = $_GET["p"]; in the following code I get an error message:  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\Store_Locator\test2.php on line 23. However, when I use $myVariable = 1; everything works fine! This is my problem. I can't say that$myVariable = 1 because it depends on the $_GET.

Comment: if(isset($_GET["p"]))
{
 //var_dump($_GET["p"]); // This var_dump displays the correct number which is correct but when I put it in a variable I get the error

 $myVariable = $_GET["p"]; // When I write $myVariable = 1; it works!
 
  echo '<p><strong>ID:</strong> '.$xml->ROW[$myVariable]->FIELD1.'</p>'; // ID: 1
} 

By the way, I am trying to display data from an XML file.

Comment: Line 23 is the line where you're getting you're data from the xml i'm assuming?
Manually set $myvariable = 215; does it work? 
The error you're getting means you don't have anything on index 215

Comment: Yes, when I set $myvariable = 1; It works fine. But when I do $myVariable = $_GET["p"]; It seems like the number changes when I get it with the $_get methode?

Comment: Your example shows you're trying to get the number 215, not 1, try this:

http://www.example.com/test.php?p=1

Comment: I don't know how to write my code here in a normal way??

Comment: Yes, 215 is a generic example. In my code I have: example.com/test.php?p=1

Comment: Don't write your code here, edit your question to add stuff. 

Get your variable and echo it, and see the result:

$myvariable = $_GET["p"]; echo $myvariable;die;

Comment: Try to echo your variable and show us the results ?

$myvariable = $_GET["p"]; echo $myvariable;die;

Comment: $myvariable = $_GET["p"]; echo $myvariable;die;  Displays 1 which is correct. But  $myvariable doesn't behave as '1' in the code??

Comment: Then your problem isn't with getting your variable, it's with fetching from the xml file.


on Line 20, execute this: var_dump($xml->ROW[$myVariable]);die;

what do you get?

Comment: When I write $myvariable = 1;  The variable $myvariable works just fine in the code?? Strange.

Comment: Keep $myvariable = $_GET["p"], and try the var dump i mentioned above.

Comment: var_dump($xml->ROW[$myVariable]);die => null

Comment: is it possible to send you the code by PM or email?

Comment: send it to admin@ralphmelhem.com with the xml you're trying to fetch from

Comment: I made it work and updated my answer. will update your question to make it compatible with the issue. Cheers

Comment: In my answer above, under the EDIT

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) super global variable

```
 $_GET['p']
```